# How to make vimeo video autoplay on iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, embed

I'm trying to embed a vimeo video into my app using UIWebView.

Currently my code looks like this and it plays the video fine if you press play, but I would like it to play when the UIWebView loads and I'm not sure how to make that happen.

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://player.vimeo.com/video/123456?autoplay=1"];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:videoURL];
UIWebView * SignUpVideo = [[UIWebView alloc] init];

MyVideo.frame = CGRectMake(0,125,781,481);

[self.view addSubview:SignUpVideo];

[MyVideo loadRequest:requestObj];
```

This is placed under `-(void)viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autoplay URL parameter doesn't work in Mobile Safari either. I'm thinking you may be out of luck unless you can get a URL for a direct stream. But in that case you could use the AVPlayer instead of a web view and have all of the flexibility you need.

Here is an interesting discussion about the vimeo direct link URLs: [How can I find download links for vimeo videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460394/how-can-i-find-download-links-for-vimeo-videos) . However, according to that, vimeo doesn't allow that technique so you might want to take a look a the developer APIs here: https://developer.vimeo.com

Best regards.