# Vimeo video downloading through API

Tags: php, vimeo

Is there a way to get the direct download link of a vimeo video using PHP vimeo API?

I tried [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460394/how-can-i-find-download-links-for-vimeo-videos), but moogaloop's links don't work. It has be more than a year since Vimeo updated their [API](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib).

Is there any way to get a direct link/downloading videos through API/PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get vimeo mobile urls dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131952/how-to-get-vimeo-mobile-urls-dynamically)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For **Vimeo PRO** Account:

You can get the direct link for any video or all videos in your account. To get the download link for all videos you have to call the following API with your access token.

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos
```

or you can get the download link for a single video by calling the following API

```
https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/{video_id}
```

In responses, you can find `download['link']`

For more information go to
[Vimeo API Documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start)

Comment: `files` and `download` links are only returned for Vimeo PRO and Business members. If you're using API v3.4 or newer, the `access_token` must include the `video_files` scope. If you authenticate with a token that does not have `video_files` scope, the video response will not contain the `files` or `download` keys.

Comment: @tehlivi  1. If I query video like this: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/videos/138085145 with video_files access token on my side, will I be able to see download link? or only video owner can see that?   2. is this download.link on root response level?

Comment: @Toniq for better help you should create a new question, but be sure to create an [app](https://developer.vimeo.com/apps) and an `access_token` with the correct scopes and you should get the `download.link` in the response. `download.link` will display in the response in the playground when [configured](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start) correctly. If the videos are private they must be [authenticated](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication).

Comment: This question is not far off. I have created an app and used correct scopes (including video_files) but I dont get download link on above url. Note that this is not my video (since I am a basic user), not sure if this matters.

Comment: Reminder for users with Pro or Business - the download link has an expiry time, so you can't manually go to the API and expect the download link to work unless you access it reasonably quickly after the API request.