# how to get vimeo mobile urls dynamically

Tags: php, api, vimeo

I am using the vimeo advanced api to get an array of my videos, but despite the fact there is an option to use your own player (I am a vimeo pro member), and there is a list of urls for different options including mobile, I can't find away to get the mobile url.

Answer (score 2):

The Vimeo Advanced API does not currently expose source file urls.

It has been announced as a feature in the next version of the API, but no time frame has been given yet.

At the moment it has to be handled manually from your clip's video file page.

Comment: OK, I was afraid this would be the answer! Oh well, I will have to go with the embeded code for now I guess. To date I have not been overly impressed with Vimeo's claims regarding the ability to customise.  You still can't hide the big play button when the controls are hidden in the browser, and not having dynamic access to the urls makes a custom player very impractical.

Comment: You might have some luck getting early access if you contact them via https://vimeo.com/help/contact