# How to download a video from the vimeo embed link (Through Tumblr's API)

Tags: video, tumblr, vimeo

I am trying to download videos from Tumblr blogs using their API.  The tumblr api provides links to the videos but they are `iframe` links, like the following format:

```
"player": [
    {
    "width": 250,
    "embed_code": "<iframe src=\"//player.vimeo.com/video/47408739?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0\" width=\"250\" height=\"140\" frameborder=\"0\" title=\"Worlds: The Kepler Planet Candidates\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>"
    }
]
```

Is there a way that I could actually download that video, seeing as how all that the API provides is a link to vimeo, rather than an actual .mp4 file or something.

There was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460394/how-can-i-find-download-links-for-vimeo-videos) but it seems the api has changed, and they are dealing more specifically with vimeos api, whereas I am interested in doing this through tumblr.

Thanks!

Comment: From a Tumblr perspective, this is not possible as it only stores the `embed_code` not a link to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vimeo does not support any technique for downloading third party videos. The only way to access video files for Vimeo videos is to have a PRO account, and access videos you already own.

Answer (score 0):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-downloadhelper/lmjnegcaeklhafolokijcfjliaokphfk?hl=en-US

Chrome browser extension. Like web scrapping technology, this extension scraps the webpage's backend source and identifies all available videos on the webpage. Then, if the video (like from the Vimeo website) has multiple resolutions to view/download, it also shows those and lets you download the desired version. After accessing the entire video on the webpage, it aggregates it and saves it on your computer, which you can play in your Media Player. I downloaded the embedded Vimeo video player of Matthew McConaughey's event Art of Livin' because it wasn't available directly to download by going to the page source (inspect element in browser) and extracting it.