# VideoController class not working anymore

Tags: php, file, url, video, vimeo

Hello i have benn using your class for getting the file url from vimeo videos in a website and the function stopped working

The Class is in here

[How can I find download links for vimeo videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460394/how-can-i-find-download-links-for-vimeo-videos)

This is waht de `$xPath` gets

```
DOMXPath Object
(
    [document] => (object value omitted)
)
```

These are the errors im getting.

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Misplaced DOCTYPE declaration in Entity, line: 2 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in Entity, line: 119 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag nav invalid in Entity, line: 124 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in Entity, line: 289 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag time invalid in Entity, line: 299 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag footer invalid in Entity, line: 375 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag section invalid in Entity, line: 378 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag section invalid in Entity, line: 404 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag section invalid in Entity, line: 430 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag section invalid in Entity, line: 452 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag aside invalid in Entity, line: 470 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in Entity, line: 511 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag aside invalid in Entity, line: 557 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in Entity, line: 558 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): End tag : expected '>' in Entity, line: 753 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

**Warning**:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : scr in Entity, line: 753 in **/home2/panterae/public_html/wp-2014/wp-content/themes/pantera/functions.php** on line **629**

Can you help me to make it work again ? or tell me why is not workinkg anymore?

Maybe vimeo block my website IP ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The code you linked to is not a method Vimeo supports for accessing video files. The only supported way of generating download links is through the API. Any other method of accessing video files can break at any moment, without any warning.

Read Vimeo's getting started guide to learn more about the API: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start

Both download links and playable url links will show up in a video response. The easiest way to find video responses is through the `/me/videos` endpoint.

`GET https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos`

This will return all videos associated with the authenticated user.

- **If** the authenticated user is PRO you will see playable video file links
- **If** the authenticated user is PRO, and the owner of the API app you will see download links.